# Are the "half your deen" hadiths authentic?

Tags: hadith, nikah, authenticity

*Question*: Are the "half your deen" hadiths authentic?

I hear it quoted often.  For example:

1. > Narrated by Anas ibn Malik, Allah’s Messenger (peace be upon him) said, “When a man marries he has fulfilled half of the ‘deen’; so let him fear Allah regarding the remaining half.” At-Tirmidhi Hadith 3096 (web source: [alquranclasses.com](https://www.alquranclasses.com/cleanliness-and-marriage-half-emaan-complete/))
2. > Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Whoever Allah provides with a righteous wife, then Allah has assisted him in half of his religion. Let him fear Allah regarding the second half.”  Source: al-Mu’jam al-Awsaṭ 992 (web source: [dailyhadith.abuaminaelias.com](http://dailyhadith.abuaminaelias.com/2013/04/16/hadith-on-marriage-whoever-gets-married-has-completed-half-of-the-religion/))
3. > At-Tirmidhi Hadith 3096 Narrated by Anas ibn Malik: Allah's Messenger (peace be upon him) said, "When a man marries he has fulfilled half of the deen; so let him fear Allah regarding the remaining half." (web source: [islamhelpline.net](http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/8512))
4. > Al-Haakim narrated in al-Mustadrak from Anas, in a marfoo’ report: “Whomever Allaah blesses with a righteous wife, He has helped him with half of his religion, so let him fear Allaah with regard to the other half.” (web source: [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/11586))

There's even a Muslim dating website named after this, namely [halfourdeen.com](https://www.halfourdeen.com/).

Comment: As far as I can tell -after a certain search- the hadith doesn't appear in jami' at-Tirmidhi at all! The most known sources for this narration are al-Mustadrak, Sho'ab al-Iman of al-Bayhaqi and at-Tabarani's awsat!

Answer (score 3):

I am translating the parts related to your question from this [answer](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/106368) which is offered by well known scholars.

> Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings
> be upon him, said, “Whoever Allah provides with a righteous wife, then
> Allah has assisted him in half of his religion. Let him fear Allah
> regarding the second half.

This hadith was mentioned by Albayhaky.

Alalbany said that it is a "Hasan" hadith (similar to authentic with less strength).

> Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings
> be upon him, said, “Whoever Allah provides with a righteous wife, then
> Allah has assisted him in half of his religion. Let him fear Allah
> regarding the second half

was mentioned by Alhakem who said it is authentic and in "Alawsat" book written by Tabarany.

Please note that what is meant to be said here is not that marriage is literely half of deen.

What this hadith means is that marriage helps a Muslim to be a rightful Muslim, because marriage helps the Muslim to be emotionally stable, and satisfies his/her human needs without committing sins.